# How to get Adobe Flash Player on elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki (64-bit) with Google Chrome

Tags: release-loki

I can't read my digital newspaper on my pc because it needs Adobe Flash to open it. I am using Elementary Loki with Google Chrome. I have tried several things from several forums which didn't work and they were all for Ubuntu and other distros or for Firefox, also I am a beginner but I have learned several useful commands.

I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

- Tried finding Canonical Partners in AppCenter, but couldn't find any.
- Tried to find support for Chrome, only found for Firefox and nothing worked.
- Tried `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`
- Tried downloading `flash.tar.gz` and

  ```
  cd /tmp
  tar -xvf flash.tar.gz
  if ! [ -d /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ ]; then
    sudo mkdir /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin ;
  else
    echo /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/ already exists ;
  fi
  sudo cp -f libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/
  sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
  ```

  and got an error:

  ```
  cp: cannot stat 'libflashplayer.so': No such file or directory
  ```

elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki (64-bit)
Processor: Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 3,9 GB
Graphics: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post but I ran across this post while looking into my own issue and figured I would provide the solution I found.

In Chromium: After installing the "pepperflashplugin-nonfree" I was able to enable it in Chromium and access content as usual. I suspect bugs (or what have you) have been corrected since this post.

Below commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

With Firefox: I was able to get the "libflashplayer.so" file from here @ [Adobe Flash Player](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).  After downloading the tar.gz file, I copied and pasted the file in "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins".

Then, I restarted the browser in firefox and was golden from there.

This info came from here @ [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-flash-plugin-view-videos-animations-games#w_installing-the-flash-plugin-manually).

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Install It using : 
`~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Answer (score -1):

Getting flash to work reliably on new versions of Chrome can be a bit of a pain in Linux. I've had mixed results. But this might get you started:

1. Make sure you have pepperflash (Chromes flash alternative) installed on your system

   ```
   sudo apt install synaptic
   ```
2. Within Synaptic search on pepperflash and check the box then install it
3. Go [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?hl=en) for the Google Chrome support with instructions on how to enable flash within Chrome

Comment: I've installed Synaptic and also pepperflash, even followed all chrome configurations from your link, still when I click on the newspaper link it takes me to adobe page. I really need this to work to prove a point to some friends. They think that GNU/LINUX is still too limited. But I know better, I run pretty much everythin in it, the only glitch has been this Flash Player. I would welcome more ideas, but if you have no further instructions, I would like to say that I really appreciate you support, it meant  a  lot!!!

Comment: Like I said, flash is really buggy in Chrome. You might want to run Firefox for that. Also have you tried the default browser, Epiphany?

Comment: I use Firefox to read my digital newspaper but the reason why I was using Chrome is that I also have Netflix and it won't run on Firefox. So, I thought that I could get only one browser to do both things, perhaps Firefox, and this would also show my friends that it wasn't that hard to make the transition to GNU/Linux. Nevertheless, this is not a dealbreaker for me. I am happy and grateful with the GNU/Linux. And once again, your help has proven vital and I can't thank you enough!

Comment: On Firefox, I can open Netflix, but when I try to play a series or movie I get the following error:

Whoops, something wentr wrong...
Playback Error
There appears to be a problem with Firefox that is preventing Netflix from starting playback.
Please ensure that you are on the latest version of Firefox.
Error Code: F7701-1003

Comment: I think this might resolve your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/912544/netflix-on-firefox-53-0-64-bit-not-playing-back

Comment: Fantastic!!! It worked just fine, thank you so much!!!